# use data-dog for testing a web app

Tags: testing, webdriver-io, datadog

I am using webdriver-io to test a web-app, the test automation framework runs every day and stores the result in json files. Can I use the data from these json files to create a dashboard. Is this possible?

Comment: What is the relation to Datadog?